# Screen Resolution Too Small

Tags: resolution

I loaded 11.10 onto an older Dell laptop. I have a normal 1024 x 768 resolution when booting from a USB drive, but when I boot from the installation on the hard drive I have a small screen in the upper left hand corner. The resolution is at 800 x 600 with no other choices in the settings display. Any ideas

Comment: What video card do you have ?

Comment: Not sure. It is a Dell Inspiron 1100.

Comment: Try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/664012/second-screen-resolution-nvidia-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 3):

You can change screen resolution size via CLI , use following cmd:

```
xrandr
```

(It will show you current screen resolution and available modes.

Now you can change the size by issuing this cmd:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1024x768
```

Sample output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 256 x 256, current 644 x 480, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected primary 644x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   644x480       50.00*
```

**Note:**

(change the VGA-0 according to what xrandr shows vga syntax for your card, in my example it shows VGA-0)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to check additional drivers and use proprietary drivers.  The reason being -- is that Ubuntu isn't running on your native graphics card.  First you'll need to find out what graphics card you have.

Open up "Terminal," and type: `lspci | grep VGA`

Once you know what video card you have, search for Linux support for that driver and download its support (usually there should be a package that will find your driver and update your system when you install the driver).  This might be risky business because the company you download the support from may not update, potentially causing problems in the future.

Once you've made your installation, restart the computer.  You should be able to leave 2D mode and use Ubuntu as you did before you installed it.  Now your resolution should work.