# Second Screen Resolution Nvidia (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: nvidia, screen, display-resolution, nouveau

**Skip to bold part for problem description**

**Edit (After 1 year)**
After Ubuntu 16.04 LTS release i am having more problems with second screen. The solution below i wrote before doesn't work. It has worked for Ubuntu 14.

Hi, I am new to Linux. This is my 3rd format in 3 months.

**I have 2 screen with same resolutions. Both 1920x1080. Nvidia GPU drivers  from X.org server**

**First screen resolution is ok. Second screen resolution is not going higher than 1024 like in the picture from my system.**

[image]

**Edit:** As suggested i added more information about my system.

```
$ sudo lshw
...
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: G94 [GeForce 9600 GT]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: a1
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
            resources: irq:27 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fa000000-fbffffff ioport:d800(size=128) memory:fea80000-feafffff
```

Full output:http://paste.ubuntu.com/12143351/

```
$ xrandr --verbose
...
DVI-I-2 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (0x6f) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x62
    Timestamp:  346406
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    dithering depth: auto 
        supported: auto, 6 bpc, 8 bpc
    dithering mode: auto 
        supported: auto, off, static 2x2, dynamic 2x2
    scaling mode: Full 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    color vibrance: 150 
        range: (0, 200)
    vibrant hue: 90 
        range: (0, 180)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: auto, off, on
    subconnector: DVI-A 
        supported: Unknown, DVI-D, DVI-A
  1024x768 (0x6f)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x73)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x74)   36.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  848x480 (0x7a)   33.8MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  864 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock   31.0KHz
        v: height  480 start  486 end  494 total  517           clock   60.0Hz
  640x480 (0x7b)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
```

Full output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12143387/

```
$ lspci -v
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device 1043
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fa000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at d800 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at fea80000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Full output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12143392/

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12143403/

```
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

No such file or directory. Probably i have to create one in recovery mode.

**Edit 2:** I created xorg.conf file on root shell. But the name has extension. So i made something like... and it gives the link.

```
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.08222015
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12151283/

**Edit 3:** I am getting closer. I run 3 command like below.

```
cvt 1920 1080 60.00
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-2 1920x1080_60.00
```

Resolution changes but not as should be. Screen-shot here. Not actual screenshot, made it on gimp since OS doesn't see black sides. It doesn't scale the width.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this question is not suited to ubuntuforums being about debugging a particular problem; nevertheless, you might get help here by providing more information. Try uploading the results of the following commands for a start and linking to them: `sudo lshw` `xrandr --verbose` `lspci -v` `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log` - this will produce a lot of information so use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ to upload the output (just copy the whole contents of your terminal) and get a web link to put here.

Comment: Oh and `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf` in case it exists.

Comment: @D.J.Duff I wonder where this question is suitable! Many times this problem asked here and none of them have solution. I will do what you sad and paste here.

Comment: @D.J.Duff   I edited the question.  I hope it have something. BTW i have format again cause some things got broken with my Ubuntu install. Probable cause i followed some instructions to solve this problem.

Comment: Emrah, I notice you are using the "nouveau" drivers rather than the proprietary nvidia drivers. Is there any particular reason for this? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia in case you want to try installing the binary drivers (be careful here - you might kill your X till you can purge your changes - and note everything that you do).

Comment: It was Nvidia before and didn't work either. I am changing it back to Nvidia. And giving one more shoot.

Comment: This is frustrating. I installed nvidia drivers by terminal running command is: (restarted)

-**sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 **

-And when i try to ad a new mode by:

-**xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 1920x1080_60.00**

-I am getting this error.

+**X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
+  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
+ Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
+ Serial number of failed request:  33
+  Current serial number in output stream:  34**

Comment: I made it easily with Nvidia X Server Setting.

Comment: @atilkan, No EDID data from DVI-I-2, either you are using a cheap adapter to VGA/HDMI or bad cable ! Could you mention how are you connecting the external monitor?

Comment: @Sneetsher i wrote the solution down below.

Comment: @atilkan, yep I see thank you +1 :) voted up already, but my interest in root cause, are connecting both monitors using direct DVI-I cables? Have they the same brand/model?

Comment: @Sneetsher They are same brand. Very similar models but not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Solved]**

I had to broke things couple of times and formatted 3 times.
I followed some steps on the link. Not all steps but made it. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors

**Shortly**

I declared a new display setting on Nvidia X Server Setting. And by saving it to correct place made it persistent after reboot.

**-SOLUTION**

- Check if you have the right driver. It should be from Nvidia. See image.

[image: check driver]

- Open **Nvidia X Server Settings** by searching computer or by **terminal command below**:

**if installed:**

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

**If it is not installed. Do this:**

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

- And choose **X Server Display Configuration**. It should look something like the image below.

[image]

- Choose second screen, in my case it is **CRT-1**.
- Open **Configuration** drop-down menu. Choose **New X Screen**. And Click **Advanced** at the bottom.

[image]

- Then you should see **Resolution** settings inputs. Enter your Screen resolutions. It may come with like 1024x768. Change it to your need. I could  not change **ViewportOut**. But we can Proceed.

[image]

- Last part is saving those settings.

After entering your resolution there is a button at the bottom 
**Save to X Configuration File** .

Click it and save the file to this destination.
**/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

- Reboot and go to **Settings** > **Diplays** you will see more options at resolution drop-down.

[image]

**I hope i can save 3 days of someone else's time.**