# Low display resolution Nvidia GeForce 9600 GT

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, display-resolution

I'm an Ubuntu Newbie and I have an issue  with the low display resolution of the Nvidia GeForce 9600 GT which i can't change. 
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] [10de:0622] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology Device [10b0:0401]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

I'm using the NVIDIA binary driver-version 340.76 and I think I have downloaded from the Nvidia's website.

What can I do?

Your support is more than welcome!

Comment: You need to add some info to get a helpful answer. Edit your question to include 1. Did you install Nvidia's drivers or are you using the ones standard with Ubuntu?  2. If you installes Nvidia's dirvers, how did you install them; via Ubuntu's "additional drivers" window or via the package you downloaded directly from Nvidia's website.

Comment: Which kernel driver you use? Enter the following: <pre><code>$ lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 </code></pre> Please add the Output to your Question.

Comment: I have the same GPU. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue:
[Second Screen Resolution Nvidia (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664012/second-screen-resolution-nvidia-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

**Shortly**

I declared a new display setting on Nvidia X Server Setting. And by saving it to correct place made it persistent after reboot.

**-SOLUTION**

- Check if you have the right driver. It should be from Nvidia. See image.

[image: check driver]

- Open **Nvidia X Server Settings** by searching computer or by **terminal command below**:

**if installed:**

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

**If it is not installed. Do this:**

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

- And choose **X Server Display Configuration**. It should look something like the image below.

[image]

- Choose second screen, in my case it is **CRT-1**.
- Open **Configuration** drop-down menu. Choose **New X Screen**. And Click **Advanced** at the bottom.

[image]

- Then you should see **Resolution** settings inputs. Enter your Screen resolutions. It may come with like 1024x768. Change it to your need. I could  not change **ViewportOut**. But we can Proceed.

[image]

- Last part is saving those settings.

After entering your resolution there is a button at the bottom 
**Save to X Configuration File** .

Click it and save the file to this destination.
**/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

- Reboot and go to **Settings** > **Diplays** you will see more options at resolution drop-down.

[image]